# iOS App Distribution as a private app

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-vpp

I'm developing an iOS Mobile Learning App for a US based Client ( lets call it ABC)  which is meant to be distributed to its employees and its Channel partners. ABC prefers that the app be distributed as a private app rather than hosting it in the app store.

In this regard, I have few queries

1. Can I publish the app in ABC's name in the app store using our developer credentials ?
2. Can I use the Enterprise developer license of ABC to distribute the app privately to its employees and channel partners ?  Is there a limit for the number of apps that can be distributed ?
3. If question no.2 is not possible, can we use the Volume Purchase program to distribute the app to the employees and channel partners ? In this case, can we , as the development team publish the app and let ABC purchase and distribute the app to its employees and channel partners using the VPP program ? Is there a volume limit for the number of apps purchased and distributed ?

In short, what is the best way to distribute an app as a private app to ABC's employees and channel partners ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the [Volume Purchase Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) for Business is the only option other than the App Store.

Apple:

> Distribute to authorized buyers that you identify, giving your customers privacy and security.
>
> Custom apps are distributed privately to authorized Volume Purchase Program for Business members that you identify in iTunes Connect. Customers sign in and purchase their apps on the Volume Purchase Program store.

The Enterprise program is limited to company employees.

Comment: Thanks, but in VPP is there Volume limit ?

Comment: I don't know, you might check the WWDC session linked to in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the enterprise is the best option, It is not limited by number of installs or device.

Comment: But what about the "channel partners" which are not company employees?

Comment: It's not officially allowed, but your only option if you don't want the app in the App Store.

Comment: Is Apple "turning a blind eye" to this practice, that is allowing without acknowledging? I would be concerned that Apple would revoke the account.