# iOS application distribution to limited audience

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval, ad-hoc-distribution

The factors I need to take into account are the following:

1) B2B is not supported for my country

2) The application is custom business app and definitely does not target the wide audience and for this reason it will most likely not be accepted to AppStore

3) It is frustrating for customers to have to search for their UDID so I want to make the process easier by skipping collecting UDIDs

4) My clients are other companies to whom I provide the login details(username/password) via email and they use them in the application

---

EDIT:
How can I publish my app to limited audience taking into account 1-4?

Comment: and your question is...?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28941820/451475) by skipping the "Volume Purchase Option" answer.

Comment: @holex sorry if my question is not clear. I would like to know what are my options to publish to limited audience taking into account the 4 factors I listed

Comment: @Zaph how about a iTunes sync of adhoc build(.ipa)? The user connects the device with usb, syncs the build with iTunes and that is all. I only need to send them the .ipa build and I won't need to know their udid.

Comment: For AdHoc there are two limitations: 1. The UDID of each device must be entered in iPhone Portal. 2. There is a limit of 100 devices and the list can only be reset once per year.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase [Apple Developer's](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) Enterprise Program and you can distribute to anyone without submitting to AppStore and also without UDID's as well.

Comment: True, but you *may* only distribute to anyone *within your organization.* Enterprise distribution isn't meant for the OP's use case, and using it that way would violate the terms of the Enterprise Program agreement.

Comment: Also, don't the provisioning profiles expire at some point, after which the end users need to install new ones?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Hockey App](https://hockeyapp.net/features/distribution/) or [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) for releasing your app to a selected number of audience ?

Comment: Please consider using the comments feature and reserve answers for full answers that solve the question. This allows future visitors to see the solution without the noise of discussion in the answers section.